# Can Spring Boot help to prevent XSS in Rest API?

Tags: spring-boot, security, xss

I have a Spring Boot 2.7.6 application with webflux instead of mvc. The application provides an Rest Api which accepts Content-Type application/json.

Example Json Request:

```
[
  {
    "id": "UP25",
    "value": "<Script>alert(2)</Script>Peter"
  },
  {
    "id": "UP31",
    "value": "239000"
  }
]
```

The request data should be stored in database in a following up process. As it contains dangerous script code it is an "Stored Cross Site Scripting" attack.

I read that Spring Security can help with XSS Protection. Does that filter out such XSS code as well?

If not, is there another Spring Boot mechanism witch helps filtering out that suspicious data?